# php image upload using curl request

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to upload an image file to the server through **imageUploader.php**. I need to upload images from both of my angular script and php script. My angular http request successfully upload the image but the php script failed to upload the image file.

This is the angular request:

```
fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', file);

    $http
    .post(uUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
        }
    })
```

and this is the php request

```
    $data['file'] = new CurlFile( $data_string['tmp_name'], $data_string['type']); 

    if (! isset ( $this->conType ))
        $this->conType = 'multipart/form-data';
    $ch = curl_init ( $this->baseUrl  ); 
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST" );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); 
    $this->addHeader ( 'Content-Type', $this->conType ); 
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->headerArray );
    $result = curl_exec ( $ch );

    public function addHeader($k, $v) {
        array_push ( $this->headerArray, $k . ": " . $v );
    }
```

The thing is that if I remove the **multipart/form-data** part in the php script, the image is successfully uploaded, but when I view it in the server, the image content can't be viewed. It's like the image is corrupted while uploading the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it will help you to uploadfile using curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
//$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/path/to/image.jpeg');
$data['file'] = new CurlFile( $data_string['tmp_name'], $data_string['type']); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD defaulted to true in 5.6.0
//So next line is required as of php >= 5.6.0
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: it give's me this error **The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class instead**